# Is it possible to create an OWIN application that can be hosted both as standalone app and inside IIS in the same time?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, owin

I want to create an OWIN/WebAPI application that has two different deployment possibilities:

1. As an standalone app (OWIN self hosted) as it might be part of a toolkit.
2. As an web application hosted inside an IIS server.

As an analogy - think of Jenkins that can be run both inside Tomcat or standalone.

I have some issues with this:

1. Do I need two different startup classes?
2. How can I build the project to generate two different assemblies (an EXE and a DLL)
3. How can I inform IIS that the app code is inside the EXE

I come from a Java background where all these are possible with moderate hassle and I am quite green in using Microsoft technologies so any pointer on how to achieve this would be beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a .NET assembly project and add all required NuGet references to this project such as ASP.NET Web API core (Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core), etc. Here you will have your ApiControllers, etc. Of course, based on your design, you will probably have domain (business rules, etc) and data access in projects of their own. So far, the projects you have will not have any hosting concerns.

Then, you create an empty ASP.NET project and reference the earlier Web API project. This way you can host your web API in IIS (ASP.NET). You can also create a console application and add NuGet packages required for OWIN hosting and of course the earlier Web API project. This is for self-hosting using Katana hosting API.

BTW, in such an arrangement, do not use any hosting specific code such as `HttpContext.Current`. Always, use framework capabilities.

PS. In case you have any problems with Web API locating your controllers, search the web for locating controllers in external assemblies.

https://www.google.com/search?q=+asp.net+web+api+locating+controllers+in+external+assemblies&oq=+asp.net+web+api+locating+controllers+in+external+assemblies